# Unable to cross-compile C in Eclipse on Windows OS

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, gcc, x86

I am trying to cross-compile (with different x86 toolchain) C code in Eclipse on windows.

Selected:

```
File->New->C Project->Empty Project
Toolchain: CrossGCC
```

I gave:

```
Cross compiler prefix: i686-pc-linux-gnu-
Cross compiler path: D:\Work\cygwin-sources-linux\toolchain\usr\bin
```

When I tried to build, I was getting below error.

```
16:15:00 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project      cross-comp ****
make all 
Building file: ../cross.c
Invoking: Cross GCC Compiler
i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP   -MF"cross.d" -MT"cross.o" -o "cross.o" "../cross.c"
make: *** [cross.o] Error 53

16:15:00 Build Finished (took 322ms)
```

I doubt why it is showing i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc instead of i686-pc-linux-gnu-gcc.exe

Answer (score 0):

Error 53 is a Windows system error meaning ["The network path was not found."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Does that help? Perhaps some file was not found by something in your build chain.

Comment: Thanks Mathew, Problem with toolchain, worked fine with another toolchain